# Bootstrap CSS logic for devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using bootstrap for developing our responsive application. According to bootstrap grid system, we can apply different css classes to our element and according to the device, corresponding css class will be applied.

This is responsive div

My question here is in which file, I will get the logic that for the device, particular css class should be applied.
e.g. For mobile devices, col-xs-12 should be applied.